# cannot insert data into database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, database, insert

I just want what my title says.I have already read all the previous similar posts but i couldn't find a solution .Could you please take a watch into my code? 
EDIT:I don't get any exception.I just don't see the new data in the database
EDIT2:The first 4 answers don't solve my problem because i edited the code and added the executenonquery command.

```
int admin = 23;
SqlConnection thisConnection = new SqlConnection(
    ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[
    "Data Source=...;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=myusername;Password=mypassword"]
    .ConnectionString);
SqlCommand nonqueryCommand = thisConnection.CreateCommand();
thisConnection.Open();
nonqueryCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Account (Username,Password,AdministratorId) VALUES (@username,@password,@admin)";

nonqueryCommand.Parameters.Add("@username", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20);
nonqueryCommand.Parameters["@username"].Value = UsernameTextbox.Text.ToString();
nonqueryCommand.Parameters.Add("@password", SqlDbType.VarChar, 15);
nonqueryCommand.Parameters["@password"].Value = PasswordTextbox.Text.ToString();
nonqueryCommand.Parameters.Add("@admin", SqlDbType.Int);
nonqueryCommand.Parameters["@admin"].Value = admin;

EDIT:nonquerycommand.ExecuteNonQuery();


thisConnection.Close();
```

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "c#" and such. That's what the tags are for.

Comment: Also, what is the exact exception you receive?

Comment: Side comment, don't store your passwords directly. Apply a strong hash function first and store *just* hash. This will give you less headache when your database is stolen.

Comment: i don't get any exception.i just don't see the new data in database

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't seem to be actually executing your query.  Execute it before you close your connection.

```
nonquerycommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 3):

Two things jump out immediately here.

1. When you retrieve the connection string from `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings` you should be passing the name of the connection string in the config file and not the connection string it self. I suspect you might not even be getting a valid connection string.
2. You need to call `ExecuteNonQuery()` on the `nonqueryCommand` instance.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
nonqueryCommand.Parameters.Add("@username", SqlDbType.VarChar,20);
nonqueryCommand.Parameters["@username"].Value = UsernameTextbox.Text.ToString();
```

Use

```
nonqueryCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", UsernameTextbox.Text.ToString());
```

And execute your query:

```
nonquerycommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 2):

Chris Farmer has the money.

Add...

```
nonqueryCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: This post doesn't say it has been edited, so it appears you saw Chris's answer and then copied it and pasted it into another answer. I am a bit confused as to why you would do that or what value that adds?

Comment: I must have read over his answer briefly.  When I posted this, all I saw on his post was "You don't seem to be actually executing your query. Execute it before you close your connection.".  I was trying to be helpful by showing you how to execute your query.

Comment: That makes more sense then. And to your credit, you got the case right on yours. :)

Answer (score 0):

you must assign connection to command before executing query
for that add following line before thisConnection.Open();

```
nonqueryCommand.Connection=thisConnection;
```

Comment: If you use connection.CreateCommand as the op has done, the connection is already assigned to the instance of the command.

Answer (score 0):

You have to execute the query and close your connection after this as shown below

```
nonquerycommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

or if you want to check if query is executed or not do this

```
if(nonquerycommand.ExecuteNonQuery()>0){ //some message or function }
```

the returned value are the number of rows affected by the statement.