# Cannot insert data into SQL Server database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I have already read all the previous similar posts but I couldn't find a solution. Could you please take a look at my code? I don't get any exception. I just don't see the new data in the database.

```
int admin = 23;

SqlConnection thisConnection = new SqlConnection(
     ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myconnectionstring"].ConnectionString);

SqlCommand nonqueryCommand = thisConnection.CreateCommand();

thisConnection.Open();

nonqueryCommand.CommandText = 
    "INSERT INTO Account (Username, Password, AdministratorId) VALUES (@username, @password, @admin)";

nonqueryCommand.Parameters.Add("@username", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20);
nonqueryCommand.Parameters["@username"].Value = UsernameTextbox.Text.ToString();
nonqueryCommand.Parameters.Add("@password", SqlDbType.VarChar, 15);
nonqueryCommand.Parameters["@password"].Value = PasswordTextbox.Text.ToString();
nonqueryCommand.Parameters.Add("@admin", SqlDbType.Int);
nonqueryCommand.Parameters["@admin"].Value = admin;

nonquerycommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

thisConnection.Close();
```

Comment: Do you get an error message?  Or just nothing happens?

Comment: Looks fine to me at first glance.  Are you sure you aren't (inadvertently) using a transaction which is then being automatically rolled back?

Comment: Don't duplicate your questions. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9932254/cannot-insert-data-into-database)

Comment: this is the only code i use for the specific table

Comment: This is a pretty odd name for a connection string: "Data Source=...;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=myusername;Password=mypassword"

Comment: i didn't know that i couldn't delete a question.I made a lot of omissions(?) in my question and 4 users answered wrong before i edited the code

Comment: i also tried to write the name of the connection string instead of the connection string itself.It doesn't matter,the mistake is somewhere else

Comment: I think you would see an error, but just in case, does the Account table have a Primary Key defined?

Comment: Please **show us** your connection string!! The code otherwise looks fine - but depending on that connection string, it might work - or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is a mistake or not, but the `ConnectionStrings` indexer in the `ConfigurationManager` is looking for the **name** of the connection string:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="SomeDB" connectionString="..." />
</connectionStrings>

ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SomeDB"].ConnectionString
```

I assume this would've caused an error in your code though, perhaps a null reference exception but I don't remember how that class works.

Answer (score 2):

You are indexing the connection strings collection with a connection string?

```
int admin = 23;

  SqlConnection thisConnection = new SqlConnection(
"Data Source=...;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=myusername;Password=mypassword");
 SqlCommand nonqueryCommand = thisConnection.CreateCommand();
thisConnection.Open();
 nonqueryCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Account (Username,Password,AdministratorId) VALUES (@username,@password,@admin)";

nonqueryCommand.Parameters.Add("@username", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20);
nonqueryCommand.Parameters["@username"].Value = UsernameTextbox.Text.ToString();
nonqueryCommand.Parameters.Add("@password", SqlDbType.VarChar, 15);
nonqueryCommand.Parameters["@password"].Value = PasswordTextbox.Text.ToString();
nonqueryCommand.Parameters.Add("@admin", SqlDbType.Int);
nonqueryCommand.Parameters["@admin"].Value = admin;

 nonquerycommand.ExecuteNonQuery();


 thisConnection.Close();
```

You need to fix up the connection string.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are pulling the connection string incorrectly. The ConfigurationManager.Connectionstrings is keyed on the name of the connection string in the app/web.config file. Try using the name in the .config file or just hard-coding the connection string into the SqlConnection objects constructor.

Answer (score 0):

```
SqlConnection thisConnection = new SqlConnection(
    ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["NameOfConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
```